# Does federal tax refund check mail contain SSN or any personal information?

Tags: irs, income-tax-refund, federal-reserve, ssn

I lived in a residential apartment and someone took my federal tax-refund check mail and opened it. It's my first time to file federal tax return and I had no ideal what was in side that mail.

Does federal tax refund check mail contain SSN or any personal information? That do I need to call police to get my SSN updated?

Comment: So you have never seen the tax refund check but perhaps found only an envelope with printed return address showing that it was sent by the IRS or by the US Treasury and no other indication that the check inside was for you? Usually, checks come in envelopes with windows from which the recipient's name and address (printed on the check) are visible and the envelope itself has no indication to whom the letter/check is being sent. Incidentally, the police cannot "update" or change your SSN; only the Social Security Administration can issue you a new SSN, after a lot of paperwork.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes. I got an opened envelop with a a window, and a check(a single paper of the size of an envelop) with my name and address. Is that all? or was there anything else in it?

Answer (score 3):

You have the check and the envelope.

Examine the envelope carefully, including the gummed flap that is used to seal the envelope. If it looks like the gum was never utilized (and the check shows no signs of having been pulled out and stuffed back in), it could just be a glitch at the sender's end where the automated printer/envelope stuffer/gummed flap sealer missed your envelope for some reason. If so, there is probably little to worry about, especially if you have a mailbox with a lock (usually in the lobby or mailroom of the apartment complex) into which a US Postal Service employee (mail carrier) puts the mail. If the mail is delivered in a sack to the doorman/office manager who is responsible for distributing it into individual mailboxes or hands your mail to you as you walk past him to the elevator, talk to the responsible person and complain about the opened envelope. If the envelope was properly sealed and has been cut open (and perhaps the check shows signs of having been  pulled out and stuffed back in), then you have more problems to worry about.

Comment: Thank you. but in this case, I had exactly "If the envelope was properly sealed and has been cut open (and perhaps the check shows signs of having been pulled out and stuffed back in), then you have more problems to worry about." Do I need to call police and update my SSN?

Comment: Since you seem to be saying that you _have_ the check in your hand/back in your apartment, the first thing to do is **look** at it to figure out what personal information has been revealed to whomsoever tampered with the envelope. Name and address for sure, but what about SSN which is what you seem most worried about? Does the check have your SSN printed on it? Also, **how** does the check get into your mailbox, and is the mailbox locked or just a cubbyhole into which your incoming mail is put? Tampering with US Mail is a Federal offense, so local police will be uninterested in your complaint.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I would assume it's obvious that whatever information is printed on the check could have potentially been exposed, and that OP knows exactly what that information is. The question seems to be *do these mailings generally include other information on __other papers that may no longer be present in this particular envelope__?*

Comment: @yoozer8 The last paper refund check I got from the IRS was in the 1970s and I don't remember if there was any other paperwork in the envelope. I _have_ received refunds occasionally in the past 40 years, but they have been deposited directly into my checking account. So I have no information about what current IRS practice is regarding what additional paperwork there might have been in the envelope.. The OP should wait for someone else to answer.